# How to use Association field in Symfony EasyAdmin 4

Tags: symfony, symfony5, easyadmin

When I use:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
      return [
            AssociationField::new('XYZ')
        ];
    }`
```

I get error `"Object of class App\Entity\XYZ could not be converted to string"`

When I add `->autocomplete()` to the `AssociationField::new('XYZ')`, then it works, but on save it displays error `"Expected argument of type "?string", "App\Entity\XYZ" given at property path "XYZ".`

Whats the CORRECT way to use this field with many to one relation? Symfony Easy Admin documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/EasyAdminBundle/fields/AssociationField.html doesn't help at all.

Comment: Also, how can I show option details (for example id, name etc.)? Right now it displays Position#1, Position#2 etc. which doesn't represent what's inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your entity `App\Entity\XYZ` will be converted to a string in your association field (which is a standard symfony entity type). Otherwise there is no way to set a label in your entity select.

It will try to convert it using the **__toString** method, so you need to add it in your entity.

For example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=XyzRepository::class)
 */
class Xyz
{
  public function __toString(){
    return $this->name; //or anything else
  }
```

EasyAdmin should be able to guess the entity class, so you don't have to specify it like you would for a simple `EntityType`.

Comment: You. are. a. wizard. 

Thank you so much! This should be in the official docs as a base explanation of this field...

Comment: One more question: can I add a functionality do ADD new record from that field if it doesn't exist?

Comment: You could create your own field to handle this case, however you cannot do it by configuring your association field. Which is basically just a select of entities (multiple or not) with an optionnal autocomplete.

Comment: Understood. How I can enable multiple select? Right now it allows to choose only one position.

Comment: If you look into `AssociationField` you can see it use `setFormType(EntityType::class)` which mean your field is just an `EntityType`, then you can look into the symfony documentation for this type and look at every options available. In your case you can find `multiple`: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple

However it will only work if your property allow multiple values (ManyToMany, OneToMany)

Comment: Then you have to use `setFormTypeOption`:

`AssociationField::new('XYZ')->setFormTypeOption('multiple', true);`